# Change login timeout when logging in into Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, timeout, tty

On my Login Screen I have to input a 32 character insane password, and the timer expires before I'm done entering password.

I've tried searching for how to change the timer that controls when an login attempt is reset. I'm having a hard time finding the solution, maybe because I'm not searching correctly. I've found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144303/change-tty-login-timeout-archlinux), which describes what I'm searching for, but can't find it for Ubuntu. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

It's only the timeout for the login screen I'm interested in changing, not the session timeout after a successful login. I'm logging in via console through VMware vSphere. SSH is closed down due to security concerns. Copy/paste option is removed due to security concerns.

Comment: In my Ubuntu 20.14 I don't have a limit on entering the password on the login screen, only on the console login there is a 60s timeout

Answer (score 8):

in my ubuntu, I can edit the file `/etc/login.defs` and change the line

```
LOGIN_TIMEOUT           60
```

To another value

Comment: This timout only changes the login-timout on the console-login, not on the graphical login, there seems to be no timeout in Ubuntu 20.04 but I am interested in changing the timeout you have to wait after you entered a false password

Answer (score 0):

There is no such 60s delay in the graphical login in Ubuntu 20.04, but you can change the delay after a **failed login attempt**:

Edit the file

```
sudo vim /etc/pam.d/login

# Enforce a minimal delay in case of failure (in microseconds).
auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=1000000
```

(default was 3000000 = 3 seconds)

There seems to be a delay though, that prevents you from entereing the password again after a failed attempt. Related question:

[Change the delay that occurs after entering an incorrect password in the graphical Login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245693/change-the-delay-that-occurs-after-entering-an-incorrect-password-in-the-graphic)

Comment: it's not about the delay. The question is about time out. The server ask for login, you type login hit enter, and then you have X time to enter password or terminal will go back to asking for login. The author has long complex pwd and unable to type before such time out happens